# Ya existe la etiqueta macros, lo correcto es macro ¿o no?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

---

NOTA: Esta pregunta es acerca de si lo correcto es usar la forma plural o singular del término "macro"

---

[macros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) tiene 13 preguntas sin embargo al [buscar macro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=macro) en este momento la búsqueda devuelve 139. Quien sabe cuantas preguntas correspondan a esta tipo de programación y no incluyan el término.

Me parece que `macro` debería existir como etiqueta pues:

1. Es el nombre correcto, por ser un sustantivo en singular
2. Es un tipo de programación con el que mucha gente está familiarizada, por ejemplo los usuarios de Excel,

En caso de que la comunidad acepte la creación de la etiqueta `macro`, la otra, `macros`, podría marcarse como sinónimo de esta.

Entre los beneficios están,

específicos

- [hipótesis] Se atraería mas usuarios que *gogleen* `macro`, por ejemplo, [macro para validar direcciones de correo](https://www.google.com/search?q=macro%20para%20validar%20direcciones%20de%20correo)

como lo tienen cualquier etiqueta

- facilitar dar seguimiento a las preguntas sobre el tema
- los usuarios que participen, podrían recibir las medallas de la etiqueta

Referencias

- [Inicio rápido: Crear una macro](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Inicio-r%25C3%25A1pido-Crear-una-macro-741130ca-080d-49f5-9471-1e5fb3d581a8?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES&fromAR=1) Ayuda de Microsoft Office
- [Definición de MACRO](http://definicion.de/macro/), página de Deconceptos.com
- [Macro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro), página de Wikipedia en español

Comment: Parece que esta etiqueta es y ha sido problemática en [so]: [What to do about \[macros\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256623/1983854), [Should the \[Macro(s)\] tag be removed from VBA questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138044/209901). Mirando la [wiki de macros](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) se ve que pide no usarla para VBA / MS-Office. No conozco demasiado esta tecnología, pero sugiero revisar esas discusiones para no tener que repetirlas por aquí en el futuro.

Comment: Esa etiqueta no tiene descripción. Difícilmente se puede afirmar que su uso sea correcto o incorrecto cuando ni siquiera está definida.

Comment: Ah pues si la discusión es sobre si usar singular o plural, creo que hemos discutido mucho respecto otras cosas jaja

Comment: La verdad este hilo me llevó por "caminos insospechados" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**Aclaración**
Lo dicho a continuación es mi opinión y sólo mía, la cual me reservo el derecho a cambiar en cualquier momento y sin aviso alguno. Esta opinión **no es** una síntesis de las otras respuestas ni de los votos que han recibido, por lo que no deber considerarse como declaración de la comunidad.

---

Luego de las leer las respuestas y comentarios<sup>1</sup> e investigar un poco y considerar las circunstancias actuales de SOes llegué a la conclusión de que la discusión en general sobre el uso del singular/plural de términos es irrelevante en estos momentos así como también que [macros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) y [macro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro) son [meta etiquetas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1507/qu%C3%A9-es-una-meta-etiqueta/) y que es importante traducir el FAQ sobre las etiquetas.

Por lo anterior, dí el primer paso y publiqué y luego "terminé" de traducir:

[¿Cómo etiqueto correctamente mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1504/)

> Nota: Como revisión 1 traduje la pregunta y puse la auto-respuesta en inglés como wiki de comunidad.

Posteriormente revisaré de nuevo las preguntas con [macros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros), lo más seguro es que lo que proceda sea aplicar

- [excel-macro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-macro) si la pregunta tiene que ver con la grabadora/gestora de macros
- [excel-vba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) si se trata de una función definida por el usuario o algo independiente de la grabadora/gestora de macros

En cuanto a si una u otra etiqueta prevalecerán, dependerá de si la comunidad edita los wikis, agrega las etiquetas a preguntas, vota para que una sea sinónimo de la otra o para manejarlas de forma indpendiente.

**Notas:**
<sup>1</sup>: Si se pudiera marcar como respuesta aceptada el [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461/ya-existe-la-etiqueta-macros-lo-correcto-es-macro-o-no?noredirect=1#comment4040_1461) de José Antonio Dura Olmos, lo marcaría como tal.

Comment: Apenas tres casos de uso no creo que valgan para definir el uso de una etiqueta. Jorgesys y yo hemos documentado el uso en [so], que podría ser más útil que simplemente eliminarla.

Comment: Actualmente hay dos preguntas con [tag:macros]. Véase también http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35784673#35784673

Comment: PaperBird Master, experto en c++, utiliza la etiqueta "macros" en una de sus preguntas. Lo argumenta razonablemente en el chat comentando que que se usa en [so]. Aún así optas por declararla "meta etiqueta" y sugerir su eliminación. No estoy de acuerdo. Dejemos que los expertos hablen de un tema y no creemos un debate donde no lo hay. Como documenté en mi respuesta, en [so] sí se usa y el problema que intentan resolver es de cómo usarla juntamente con Excel y VBA. Con c y c++ debería mantenerse.

Comment: Yo no tengo autoridad para declarar una etiqueta como meta-etiqueta, sólo tengo autoridad para declarar mi opinión, la cual me reservo el derecho de debatir  y cambiar ;)

Comment: P.D. El aceptar una respuesta no es una declaración perenne ni tampoco declara una "discusión" como "cerrada".

Comment: Mi punto es que abrir un debate, recibir respuestas con puntuación positiva y acabar aceptando la respuesta propia, que no recibió votos positivos, es cuanto menos confuso. Máxime porque la respuesta aceptada de una discusión es la que debe ser mayoritariamente aceptada por la comunidad para así ser implementada.

Comment: Cuando la acepté no tenía votos negativos :) En cuanto a lo confuso, eso no es mi culpa, eso se resuelve conociendo como funcionan SOes.

Comment: ... Hay que entender que significa aceptar una respuesta, qué significan los votos. Los comentarios que he recibido al momento, podría decirse que también son confusos. Hasta este último, me resultó claro cual era tu confusión.

Comment: He agregado una aclaración. Espero que eso ayude a disipar la supuesta confusión.

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como escribí en los [comentarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461/ya-existe-la-etiqueta-macros-lo-correcto-es-macro-o-no#comment4038_1461) hace unos días y expone Jorgesys en [su respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1494/83), es bueno fijarse en cómo lo hizo Stack Overflow inicialmente.

Allí vemos que actualmente [macros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) es la etiqueta principal, siendo [macro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro) un sinónimo de esta. La lista de sinónimos aparece en la sección [*tag synonyms*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/synonyms), donde vemos que [custom-macros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-macros) también es sinónima.

Es importante destacar que el extracto de [macros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) indica:

> ***DO NOT USE for VBA / MS-Office languages. Use the respective [vba] tags instead.*** A macro is a rule or pattern that specifies how a certain input sequence (often a sequence of characters) should be mapped to an output sequence (also often a sequence of characters) according to a defined procedure.

Esto es:

> No usar para lenguajes VBA / MS-Office. Usar la etiqueta [vba] correspondiente.

Si bien cada sitio tiene que encontrar su camino, creo que es un apunte importante a tener en cuenta, máxime cuando el tema ha generado como mínimo dos discusiones extensas:

- [What to do about [macros]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256623/1983854)
- [Should the [Macro(s)] tag be removed from VBA questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138044)

Es importante destacar que en la segunda publicó [una respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138078) Shog9, Community Manager de Stack Exchange. No entiendo demasiado del tema de macros, pero por lo que veo él sugiere usar "macros" junto con VBA cuando sea específico de esta área, no junto con VBA en todos los casos.

Personalmente, estoy de acuerdo con él. Añadir más etiquetas en muchos casos ayuda, siempre y cuando sea apropiado.

Por tanto mi recomendación es: añade la etiqueta cuando sea pertinente. Si va a hacer más fácil buscar preguntas y respuestas, adelante.

En cuanto a utilizar macro o macros, supongo que es más coherente usar singular. La [entrada en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro), por ejemplo, está en singular y por lo general usar etiquetas en singular [es lo preferido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41504).

Comment: Observo tres partes, la tercera parte, abarca dos recomendaciones, 1. agregar la etiqueta cuando sea pertinente y 2. Hacer uso de la forma singular. La primera parte menciona que en SO se usa `macros` como etiqueta principal y macro como sinónimo. La segunda parte abarca el tema del contenido, pero no era el propósito de esta pregunta. Te invito a revisar el wiki y si lo consideras apropiado editarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente comparo las [etiquetas en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) para tener una referencia sobre estas y agregarlas a SO en español.

La etiqueta que tiene descripción es [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) mientras que [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) no la tiene pero también cuenta con preguntas, establecer solo las dos que comento sería generalizar demasiado.

El problema es que puede existir casos como excel-macro, vba-macro, sas-macro, etc, uno más general visual-studio-macros.

Es un tema difícil de definir, establecer únicamente usar [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) o [macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macros) es generalizar, creo que lo mejor sería tratar de especificar que tipo de macro se requiere en la pregunta (excel-macro, vba-macro, sas-macro).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según entiendo las etiquetas que no tienen un "x n" es porque son sinónimos de otras etiquetas. En cualquier caso, de acuerdo contigo. Me parece que tanto macros como macro serían meta-etiquetas y que es mejor por ejemplo usar excel-macro, basic-macro y así . Gracias Jorgesys.

Comment: Creo que la comunidad del sitio en inglés se ha creado problemas innecesarios al permitir, la existencia de "facciones" y que una de ellas imponga una connotación específica a términos polisémicos. Me parece curioso como a algunas etiquetas  las llaman "[meta-tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/)" pero a otras, como macros, no. Lo mas seguro es que se deba a cuestión histórica. Ojalá tomemos "lo bueno" y dejemos "lo malo" fuera.