# ¿Cómo etiqueto correctamente mis preguntas?

Tags: soporte, faq, etiquetas

> Adaptación de [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/)

Aquí compartimos algunos consejos para etiquetar preguntas. Estos lineamientos te ayudarán a etiquetar tus preguntas de forma más precisa, lo cual a su vez ayudará a obtener más atención y conseguir mejores respuestas más rápido.

> Para más información, mira [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo debe usarlas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](/q/1378)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: Las reglas gramaticales permiten omitir los ¿? en los títulos, así que incluirlos o no en las preguntas de SOes es meramente cuestión de estilo. Referencia: http://www.academia.org.mx/espin/Detalle?id=116

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Traducción directa de https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/289691

#### Etiquetas eficaces - Llevar más atención a su pregunta

- Cada etiqueta debe sostenerse por sí mismo: si una etiqueta sólo tiene sentido cuando se utiliza en un grupo con otras etiquetas, algo está mal.  Por ejemplo, una pregunta etiquetado como `[visual]` `[studio]` (dos etiquetas) es incorrecto.
- Escoja las etiquetas que muestran los recuentos más altos en el autocompletado, ya que son más propensas a hacer que su pregunta aparezca resaltada para un usuario en la página principal o aparecer en la fuente RSS de alguien.
- Como mínimo, trate de incluir al menos una etiqueta muy amplia (es decir, `java` o `C#`) y otra etiqueta para restringir el tema hacia abajo dentro de esa categoría más amplia (es decir, `strings` o `recolección-basura` ).
- Usted está limitado a 5 etiquetas, y que por lo general es mejor tratar de utilizar todas las 5 de ellas (si hay 5 coincidencias apropiadas entre las etiquetas existentes).
- Trate de usar etiquetas amplias.  Por ejemplo, normalmente se desea incluir la versión con la etiqueta NET en lugar de la del lenguaje.  Si bien el etiquetado de una pregunta `c#2.0` podría transmitir la información que desea exactamente (que implica C#, .NET, y la versión 2.0 todo en una etiqueta), inserte en ella `c#` `.net` `.net2.0` traerá a su pregunta más *mucha* atención, ya que más gente va a ver el genérico `.net` y `C#` las etiquetas.  Hay por supuesto una disyuntiva: utilizó 3 etiquetas para transmitir la misma información que podría haber hecho con una.  Sin embargo, es difícil subestimar la cantidad de puntos de vista más las etiquetas genéricas traerán a su pregunta.

#### Los NO's del etiquetado

- **Trate de no crear nuevas etiquetas.** Si crea una nueva etiqueta, la etiqueta es un hecho que no ayudará a que la pregunta se muestre en las fuentes RSS suscritas o listas de etiquetas interesantes.  Una vez más, las sugerencias predictivas pueden ayudar a seleccionar las etiquetas apropiadas.  Lo más probable es que también significa que se está omitiendo alguna etiqueta existente para ese tema que categoriza con mayor precisión su pregunta.
- ***No* tratar de resumir su pregunta usando las etiquetas.** El punto de las etiquetas de Stack Overflow en español es ayudar a otras personas interesadas a encontrar su pregunta por clasificarlos en categorías claras y específicas.  Esto no es indexar o resumir la pregunta.  Las diferencias son sutiles, pero importantes.
- No utilice su nombre de usuario para una etiqueta.
- **No utilice [meta etiquetas](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)**. Una meta etiqueta es cualquier etiqueta que no categoriza el contenido de la pregunta.

#### Formateo

- Utilizar todo en minúsculas
- Reemplaza espacios con guiones (-) para combinar varias palabras en una sola palabra (es decir, la etiqueta "`Pruebas Unitarias` "como" `prueba-unitaria`").
- Usar `a-z` `áéíóúüñ` `0-9` `+` `#` `-` `.`. Usar otros caracteres puede hacer difícil el uso de la etiqueta en una dirección URL.
- Un número de etiquetas son anteriores a las directrices, y por lo tanto tienen un formato diferente.  Pero eso no quiere decir que usted no debe seguir estas reglas.
- Al escribir el nombre de una etiqueta, pensar en cómo alguien de google ese tema.  En la mayoría de los casos esto significa escribir el nombre completo, pero también es posible que desee utilizar la abreviatura.  Por ejemplo, "`css`" es probablemente más apropiado que "`cascading-style-sheets`".

#### Re-etiquetar

Reetiquetar una pregunta es hacer cualquier edición que cambia las etiquetas.

- **No** re-etiquetar una pregunta si no se va a añadir valor a la información de la pregunta por hacerlo.
- **Sí** re-etiquetar preguntas para agregar etiquetas conocidas y populares que sean apropiados para la pregunta.