# Sugerencia de etiqueta "Getting Started" y otras etiquetas de nivel de conocimientos

Tags: característica-nueva, etiquetas

Creo que sería tener una etiqueta llamada "Getting Started" o al ser un sitio en español, debería decir "Empezando". El sentido de esta etiqueta sería poner en contexto una pregunta en relación al dominio que se tiene de una tecnología específica como pueda ser un lenguaje de programación o un framework, que para dicha etiqueta indicaría que el nivel que posee el usuario es de principiante, si es que llega a eso. Pero también podríamos extrapolarlo a otros niveles. Así por ejemplo, podría haber 5 niveles de dominio:

- Empezando
- Básico
- Medio
- Avanzado
- Experto

A continuación describo su utilidad:

- Mostrar todas las preguntas que se puede hacer una persona o grupo de personas en relación a su dominio de la tecnología.
  Así, si nos encontramos dos etiquetas: Empezando y java, pues podemos entender que se trata de una persona que está empezando con el lenguaje de programación de java. Y eso podría ayudar a que quien escribe la respuesta sea cuidadoso en su descripción haciéndola esta en un estilo paso a paso sin omitir ningún paso ni explicación.
  Personalmente encuentro algo lento el proceso al iniciarte en un framework nuevo, desde la instalación, hasta el desarrollo de tu primera App. Por ejemplo, he tenido experiencias con Qpython, Kivy y ahora con Ionic. Cómo yo, hay mucha gente aficionada, no profesional y les cuesta significativamente empezar con cualquier herramienta de desarrollo determinada. Esto ocurre porque al seguir un tutorial ya sea en video, u en otro formato, no siempre se comporta igual tu sistema informático que aquel que está siendo usado como referencia de aprendizaje.
- Monitorear las preguntas en relación al nivel de dominio.
  Un ejemplo de esta utilidad sería para su utilización por personal de recursos humanos tener datos del dominio de un candidato de la tecnología usada en su puesto de trabajo, aunque sobre esto último entiendo que haya personas que prefieran que únicamente se tenga en cuenta su reputación simplemente.
  Si nos fijamos, la única referencia en este sitio acerca del conocimiento que tenemos sobre alguien es su reputación y esto es un poco ambiguo y general, ya que es posible que una persona haya conseguido mucha puntuación en python pero no tenga mucha idea acerca de tecnologías .NET.
- Distribuir el trabajo que se realiza en este sitio. Los de nivel Básico podían contestar las preguntas de los que están empezando, los medios contestar a las de los básicos y así sucesivamente teniendo en cuenta que los Expertos se podrían contestar entre sí. Al fin y al cabo ¿no es un poco engañoso que una persona tenga miles de puntos de reputación si los ha conseguido a base de contestar preguntas de nivel Empezando o básico?

Por último para la implementación de estas etiquetas tendríamos que solventar la cuestión importante de cómo se determina a que nivel de dominio pertenece cada pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etiquetas como las propuestas son **meta etiquetas** y estas no se permiten en el sitio.

Por otro lado tampoco se permiten publicaciones del tipo listas de cosas así que lo más probable es que algo como lo que propones se deba realizar como un proyecto paralelo o incluso como independiente.

Referencias

- [Creación de etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
- [¿Cómo etiqueto correctamente mis preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1504/65)

Answer (score 3):

No estoy de acuerdo. Esas etiquetas no describen las preguntas, describen las personas, y en el sitio, las etiquetas describen las preguntas.

El desglose que haces de su utilidad, en realidad no sirve al sitio. Yo contesto de la misma forma para cualquier nivel, trato de ser explicito e ir paso a paso. En general por el tipo de pregunta, se nota el nivel de quien pregunta.

La reputacion, como ya puse en otro lado, no da un nivel de conocimiento, si no un nivel de confianza sobre la persona en relacion con el uso del sitio. Tranquilamente podrias tener 80k de reputacion, y no saber nada sobre X tecnologia, y eso implicaria que tus preguntas sean basicas. Ademas no marcaria un nivel de conocimiento para nadie de recursos humanos (que no se si quiero que lo midan por eso), porque tranquilamente podrias ser usuario del sitio, contestar solo las preguntas que te interesan, y no por eso ser menos experto (y hay muchos casos de eso).

Y ademas, porque restringir quien contesta que cosa? no es preferible que te explique un experto en la materia, con lujo de detalles y con conocimientos avanzados que pueda darte tecnicas e ideas que por ahi a alguien de nivel medio todavia ni se le ocurrieron?

Yo pienso que estas etiquetas son confusas, ningun usuario las usaria, yo no podria calificar ninguna de mis preguntas en ningun nivel (porque siempre se puede aprender mas), y creo que solo llevaria a estigmatizar usuarios (como por ejemplo, ah sos nivel inicial, tu pregunta es mala por ser de nivel inicial).

Comment: la tuya me parece una buena contestación a mi sugerencia. Bueno no quiero ser pesaito, solo despedirme de esta sugerencia diciendo que una etiqueta de "Getting started" podría ayudar a recopilar toda la información en ese sentido para ayudar a generar material para tutoriales. A menudo me parece que la pendiente de la curva de aprendizaje en esto de los frameworks es más pequeña (y por ello un proceso más lento) al inicio de la curva. A mi me molaría tener todas las posibles preguntas (que recogen todos los problemas con los que tiene que lidiar) de un iniciado en una tecnología X.

Comment: Pero, este no es un sitio de tutoriales. Es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Ya se intento hacer un sitio de tutoriales (como documentation) y fue dado de baja. @Mr.Baldan